# org-capture date deadlines

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My projects are very deadline driven. I want to create an org-capture template that I only need to input the deadline date to the Project head line once, and all deadlines of the subtasks in the template is calculated from the project's deadline. For example.

```
;; Org-capture template 
** Project %?
DEADLINE: %^{Project Deadline}t   <- how can i use this prompt to calculate the deadlines for subtasks below
*** TODO Task 1
DEADLINE < 5 months before project headline's prompt> 
*** TODO Task 2
DEADLINE <1 months before project headline's prompt>
```

I don't want to prompt for the deadline for each subtask in the template since each project has about 20 subtasks.

Is there a way to cache the date entered in the Project's dead line `%^{Project Deadline}t` ?